# How to hide Gnupg passwords when doing back ups with Duplicity?

Tags: linux, security, backup, gnupg, duplicity

I have been following some tutorials for Duplicity back ups. It is all fine except that everyone seems to be putting their Gnupg passwords in scripts or plain text files which sounds crazy stupid thing to do to me.

Is there a way to securely hide/hash my Gpg keys when using Duplicity for backups?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-duplicity-with-gpg-to-securely-automate-backups-on-ubuntu?comment=12940

> asymmetrically encrypt the backup to a different public key by passing
>   a different key id to the "--encrypt-key" flag"

Or cache the password using gpg-agent but there is a caveat that it will not survive a reboot.

Comment: Indeed, this is what public key encryption is for... and that's what gpg is really for, not symmetric encryption.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on how to do this then?